# How to properly use a player swipe length in pixels to move UI elements in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile-devices, unity-ui

For a matter of optimization, I had to create a pooling list (acting as a scroll view) to reduce the number of gameobjects instantiated. This list use the draggable interfaces (IDragHandler, IBeginDragHandler, IEndDragHandler) to assess the player input in real time and move/reorganize its UI Elements.

All of them use RectTransform, and I modify their anchored position in the UI according to the drag length during the last frame.

However, I can't manage to synchronize my touch input, and the items movement. When swiping, my list scroll faster than my input (i.e. when swiping 130 pixels visually, my list will scroll around 180 pixels)

I tested through and through, but the values collected from input, run through the script and used in the end to offset the anchoredPosition of the RectTransform are the same, every frame, all the time. I first thought it was due to screen resolution, as the scroll rate seems to vary from a mobile device to another, but normalizing the vector regarding the screen res does not solve the problem.

Am I missing something, and/or is there an easy way (Unity Method) to fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine finally managed to solve the problem, as he stumbled upon a script modifying the scale of a parent gameObject.

Make sure to check the scales from the gameObject and its parent to ensure you have the proper ratio.